# Rails Left join query , How to create complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Hey I am trying to create a sql query in rails how can I convert this sql query into rails actvie record . The query is :

```
   SELECT  f.id, COUNT( f.id  ) AS total               
   FROM    feeds AS f LEFT JOIN feed_likes AS l
    ON f.id = l.feed_id
    GROUP   BY f.id
```

There are two tables feeds table and other one is feed_likes .

Answer (score 0):

```
YourClassName.select("feeds.id, feeds.content, count(feed_likes.id) as likes").joins("left join feed_likes on feeds.id = feed_likes.feed_id").group("feeds.id, feeds.content")
```

you aren't getting much by using ActiveRecord here, you can go right down to Arel or just use find_by_sql()

Comment: Hey If I user find_by_sql() will it work for all databases like mysql and postgres database is it ok to use  find_by_sql()

Comment: No, it won't.  find_by_sql is vendor specific.  But it's a moot point as changing db vendors doesn't happen although we always think it might.

Answer (score 0):

does this help

```
 Feed.joins("LEFT JOIN feed_likes ON feeds.id = feed_likes.feed_id").group("feeds.id").select("feeds.id, feeds.content, COUNT(feed_likes.id) as likes")
```

to match query do this

```
 Feed.joins("LEFT JOIN feed_likes ON feeds.id = feed_likes.feed_id").group("feeds.id").select("feeds.id, feeds.content, COUNT(feed_likes.id) as likes").to_sql
```

Answer (score 0):

To create this query in ActiveRecord you can use the Arel tables for each model to generate the SQL for you.
Assuming you have two ActiveRecord classes Feed and FeedLike:

```
f = Feed.arel_table
fl = FeedLike.arel_table

query = f.join(fl, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(f[:id].eq(fl[:feed_id]))
         .project(f[:id], f[:id].count.as("Total")) 
         .group(f[:id])
```

You can then use query in a where clause

Calling to_sql on the query returns the following

> "SELECT \"feeds\".\"id\", COUNT(\"feeds\".\"id\") AS Total
>
> FROM \"feeds\" LEFT OUTER JOIN \"feed_likes\" 
>   ON \"feeds\".\"id\" = \"feed_likes\".\"feed_id\
>
> GROUP BY \"feeds\".\"id\""